# Transit visa at Helsinki airport

Tags: visas, transit, finland, helsinki, hel

We are a couple from India and are spending 23 hours at Helsinki airport. Can we get a transit visa to leave the airport, see the city, stay at a hotel etc?

Comment: This is not actually a duplicate of the linked question, because the linked question is about airside transit.  This question is about leaving the airport for tourism.  To do that, you need a normal short-stay Schengen visa, no matter how short the intended stay.  (There used to be a Schengen transit visa for stays of no more than 5 days, but this was abolished in 2010.)

Comment: @phoog, please post that as an answer!

Answer (score 5):

First of all, to answer your question: No, you cannot get a transit visa; to do what you are asking about, you need a regular Schengen short-stay visa.

(There are exceptions, of course, a detailed account of which is beyond the scope of this question.  This answer assumes that you are a national of a country whose citizens require a visa to enter the Schengen area, and that you do not have another document that authorizes entry in lieu of a short-term visa.)

The general point is that to leave the airport, or indeed to pass through immigration *for any length of time,* you must meet the same entry requirements as someone seeking a short visit under the 90/180 day rule.  That is to say, there is no such thing as a "transit visa" in the Schengen visa code.

There used to be such a thing, however.  The original Schengen visa scheme comprised four types of visa.  Some internet sites continue to describe this obsolete scheme:

- A: Airport transit visa: Required of nationals of a small number of countries for transit *while remaining within the international zone of an airport.*  That is, this visa allows people to change planes in the airport, but does not allow them to pass through immigration.  Most countries' nationals are exempt from this requirement.
- B: Transit visa: Required of most countries' nationals for transit of up to five days in the Schengen area while traveling from one non-Schengen country to another.
- C: Short-term visa: Required of most countries' nationals for visits in the Schengen area of no more than 90 days in any 180-day period.
- D: Long-term visa (also called *national visa*): Required of nationals of all non-EU countries who wish to remain in a Schengen country for more than 90 days.

(Source: http://www.schengenvisainfo.com/schengen-visa-types/)

The 2009 version of the Schengen visa code, which took effect in 2010, abolished the transit visa.  Its definition of visa is (emphasis added):

> 2. ‘visa’ means an authorisation issued by a Member State with a view to:
>
>    (a) ***transit through*** or an intended stay in the territory of the Member States of a duration of no more than three months in any six-month period from the date of first entry in the territory of the Member States;
>
>    (b) transit through the international transit areas of airports of the Member States;

The visa type letters are not mentioned in the main body of the legislation, but the remaining type designations -- A, C, and D -- are specified in Annex VII:

> 7. ‘TYPE OF VISA’ heading:
>
> In order to facilitate matters for the control authorities, this heading specifies the type of visa using the letters A, C and D as follows:
>
> A: airport transit visa (as defined in Article 2(5) of this Regulation)
>
> C: visa (as defined in Article 2(2) of this Regulation)
>
> D: long-stay visa

(Source: http://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/?uri=CELEX:02009R0810-20131018)